# ASP.NET UpdatePanel cause full postback after idle

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I'm using multiple updatepanels in my SharePoint Visual Web Parts. Everything is working fine until I leave the page to idle for a while.

For example if I change a few drop downs and leave the page to idle for about 5 minutes. Coming back to the page and changing a drop down will cause a full postback.

Another example is using a gridview with pagination. Leaving the grid view on page 5. Idle for 5 minutes and come back to the page. Clicking on page 8 for example will make the gridview go to page 1.

I am new to using Updatepanels and would really appreciate some advice.

Comment: what is your session expiration time set?

Comment: where would I set this? In the sharepoint web.config file?

Comment: Sharepoint  Central Admin -> Application Management -> Configure Session State

Comment: I cannot find this setting in Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

I have solver this anonymous problem by adding this javascript. I have found that after some ideal time(~30sec) for each request it page goes for authenticate user. and if user is not authentication then it reload the whole page and re authenticate user that's why page is reload.

Add this java script code in your page which will solve your problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var isNtlmActive = false;
    var updatePannelsToUpdate = [];
    var eventTarget = '';
    var eventArgument = '';
    var causesValidation = false;
    var validationGroup = '';
    var requestBody = '';

    function initializeRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        var onSuccess = function () {
            //At this point the NTLM connection is re-established 

            var pageRequestManagerInstance;
            isNtlmActive = true;

            pageRequestManagerInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

            // re-issuing the 'original' request
            pageRequestManagerInstance.beginAsyncPostBack(updatePannelsToUpdate, eventTarget, eventArgument, causesValidation, validationGroup);
        };

        var onError = function () {
            // do something here if error occurred
        }

        if (!isNtlmActive) {
            // capturing and preserving the body as well as some other meta data about the original request
            requestBody = args.get_request().get_body();
            updatePannelsToUpdate = sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate;
            eventTarget = sender._postBackSettings.asyncTarget;
            eventArgument = '';
            causesValidation = false;
            validationGroup = '';

            // NOTE: the variable '_spFormOnSubmitCalled' is a global variable that gets injected by the logic iplemented in the 'init.js' file.  
            // Based on our observation of the logic in 'init.js' the varialbe '_spFormOnSubmitCalled' is set to true when HTML form's

            // 'onsubmit'  function is called and it is never set back to false (after we cancel the postback)
            // As the result, any subsequent attempts to submit the form do not work.
            // Thus, we excplicetely set the value back to false before we cancel the original post back request.
            //
            //'init.js'is autoatically referenced by SharePoint and included on to the 'master' page.
            // The HTML form as well as the functionality to handle submit is also provided by SharePoint.
            if (typeof _spFormOnSubmitCalled === "boolean") {
                _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false;
            }
            args.set_cancel(true);

            callServerSideServiceToReviveNtlmSession(onSuccess, onError);
        }
        else {
            // resetting the body of the request with the value captured from the original request
            args.get_request().set_body(requestBody);

            isNtlmActive = false;
            updatePannelsToUpdate = [];
            eventTarget = '';
            eventArgument = '';
            causesValidation = false;
            validationGroup = '';
        }
    }

    function getCurrentSiteCollectionUrl() {
        var url;

        url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;

        return url;
    }

    function callServerSideServiceToReviveNtlmSession(successHandler, errorHandler) {
        var siteCollectionUrl;
        var testServiceUrl;
        var spRequestExecutor;
        var request;

        siteCollectionUrl = getCurrentSiteCollectionUrl();
        testServiceUrl = siteCollectionUrl + "/_api/web/title";

        spRequestExecutor = new SP.RequestExecutor(siteCollectionUrl);
        request = {
            url: testServiceUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        };
        spRequestExecutor.executeAsync(request);
    }

    try {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            try {
                var pageRequestManagerInstance = null;

                //Note: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager gets injected into your page the minute you use ScriptManager (and UpdatePanel)
                pageRequestManagerInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

                pageRequestManagerInstance.add_initializeRequest(initializeRequestHandler);
            }
            catch (ex) {
                //alert('INNER EXCEPTION: document ready - ' + ex.message);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        //alert('EXCEPTION: document ready - ' + ex.message);
    }
</script>
```

Mark as answer if this answer found helpful...

Thanks..!!

Answer (score -1):

Enable or disable session state across the entire farm

On the taskbar, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click SharePoint 3.0 Central Administration.

In the top navigation bar, click the Application Management tab.

On the Application Management page, in the Office SharePoint Servers Shared Services section, click Configure session state.

On the Configure Session State page, in the Enable Session State section, select the Enable Session State check box to enable session state for the farm.

To specify the duration of sessions, in the Timeout section, enter a number (in minutes) in the Session should be timed out after (minutes) box. The default is 60 minutes.

Click OK to save the session state configuration.

This one will give you more guidance

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263527.aspx

if any confusion ask me,

Comment: The question is tagged Sharepoint-2013, and this answer applies to SharePoint-2007 (wss 3).